# Self defined function with dplyr functions won't accept argument values

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to use dplyr's `mutate_at` to subtract a numeric column's value (`A1`) from another corresponding numeric column (`A2`), I have multiple columns and several data frames I want to do for this for (BCDE..., df1:df99) so I want to write a function.

`df1 <- df1 %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(A1), .funs = funs(remainder = .-A2))`

Works fine, however when I try and write a function to perform this:

`REMAINDER <- function(df, numer, denom){
       df <- df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(numer), .funs = funs(remainder = .-denom))
       return(df)
}`

With arguments `df1 <- REMAINDER(df1, A1, A2)`

I get the error `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.`

Which I don't understand as I just manually called the line of code without a function and my columns are numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vignette [Programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) explains in great detail what to do:

```
library(dplyr)
REMAINDER <- function(df, numer, denom) {
  numer <- enquo(numer)
  denom <- enquo(denom)
  df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(!! numer), .funs = funs(remainder = . - !! denom))
}

df1 <- data_frame(A1 = 11:13, A2 = 3:1, B1 = 21:23, B2 = 8:6)

REMAINDER(df1, A1, A2)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>      A1    A2    B1    B2 remainder
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8         8
> 2    12     2    22     7        10
> 3    13     1    23     6        12
> ```

```
REMAINDER(df1, B1, B2)
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>      A1    A2    B1    B2 remainder
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8        13
> 2    12     2    22     7        15
> 3    13     1    23     6        17
> ```

#### Naming the result column

The OP wants to update `df1` and he wants to apply this operation to other columns as well.

Unfortunately, the `REMAINDER()` function as it is currently defined will overwrite the result column:

```
df1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 4
>      A1    A2    B1    B2
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8
> 2    12     2    22     7
> 3    13     1    23     6
> ```

```
df1 <- REMAINDER(df1, A1, A2)
df1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>      A1    A2    B1    B2 remainder
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8         8
> 2    12     2    22     7        10
> 3    13     1    23     6        12
> ```

```
df1 <- REMAINDER(df1, B1, B2)
df1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 5
>      A1    A2    B1    B2 remainder
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>     <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8        13
> 2    12     2    22     7        15
> 3    13     1    23     6        17
> ```

The function can be modified so that the result column is individually named:

```
REMAINDER <- function(df, numer, denom) {
  numer <- enquo(numer)
  denom <- enquo(denom)
  result_name <- paste0("remainder_", quo_name(numer), "_", quo_name(denom))
  df %>% mutate_at(.vars = vars(!! numer),
                   .funs = funs(!! result_name := . - !! denom))
}
```

Now, calling `REMAINDER()` twice on different columns and replacing `df1` after each call, we get

```
df1 <- REMAINDER(df1, A1, A2)
df1 <- REMAINDER(df1, B1, B2)
df1
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 6
>      A1    A2    B1    B2 remainder_A1_A2 remainder_B1_B2
>   <int> <int> <int> <int>           <int>           <int>
> 1    11     3    21     8               8              13
> 2    12     2    22     7              10              15
> 3    13     1    23     6              12              17
> ```

Answer (score -1):

I have used [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643973/sum-pairs-of-columns-by-group) in order to subtract pairs of columns in a list of data frames. My example has only 3 pairs of columns in each of the two data frames and it can work with higher number of columns and data frames.

```
dt <- data.table(A1 = round(runif(3),1), A2 = round(runif(3),1),
                 B1 = round(runif(3),1), B2 = round(runif(3),1),
                 C1 =round(runif(3),1), C2 =round(runif(3),1))

dt = list(dt,dt+dt)

lapply(seq_along(dt), function(z) {
  dt[[z]][, lapply(1:(ncol(.SD)/2), function(x) (.SD[[2*x-1]] - .SD[[2*x]]))]
})
```